# mod_rewrite RewriteRule on windows

Tags: windows, mod-rewrite, apache-2.2

I can't seem to get RewriteRule to work on Windows 7. C:\www is the DocumentRoot.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteRule ^(.*)% "C:/www/main/index.php"
</IfModule>
```

The goal is to take every incoming URL and go to index.php, but this doesn't appear to be doing anything. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you load it? Enable the logging with `RewriteLog` and `RewriteLogLevel` to see what it says.

Comment: Is the ending regex pattern really a '%' on windows, or is that a typo? In Linux it's '$'. Other than that, you could probably get rid of the ^ and %, if you really want all URLS to redirect.

Comment: % are a typo, they should be $...that was the problem. *facepalm*

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you realize that $ is end of pattern and not %